# What is the difference between these 2 String formatting?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

value

```
double value = 345.12345;
```

String Format 1

```
String str = String.format("%.02f", value);
```

String Format 2

```
String str = String.format("%.2f", value);
```

Both print the same value 345.12. So, what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [syntax for a format specifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) is

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

Note that `precision` is `02` in the first case and `2` in the second case, but since these are the same number, the output is the same. Hence `"%.02f"` and `"%.2f"` are the same.

But, if you had written `%02f`, then `flags` would be `0` ("zero-pad output up to width") and `width` would be `2`. Then the output would be zero-padded up to the specified width.

Answer (score 6):

The 0 prefix notation only works for the integer part, not the decimal part.  If you had say %07.2f instead, it would show the value as 0345.12.